# How to send date from PHP to MySQL stored procedure parameter using mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

PHP Code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("CALL `usp_AddRegistrationInfo`(?,?);");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss',$userID,$dob);
        $stmt->execute();
```

MYSQL Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `usp_AddRegistrationInfo`(IN `ID` VARCHAR(20), IN `date_of_birth` DATE)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO `tbl_userdetails` (`UserID`, date_of_birth);


END
```

In the above statements if I pass the date from PHP to MySQL its not working properly. For example if I send `1993-01-01` it is storing as `0000-00-00`. Please help me in this process.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I would think that if `$dob == '1993-01-01'`, your code should work... but perhaps MySQL does not recognize $dob as a date. Try this:

```
$dob = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dob));

$stmt = $db->prepare("CALL `usp_AddRegistrationInfo`(?,?);");
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$userID,$dob);
$stmt->execute();
```